# How to make a rake task always pass (never failed)

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a rake task, I would like to have this task always passed/successful/never failed.

Does this work?

```
task :myraketask do

begin
   mytask detail
rescue  Exception => e  
  put "to catch any exception: #{e.message}"
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following, I'd say you are right.

```
begin
   1/0
rescue
   puts "not failing :)"
end
```